# Android: Finding Similar Words

Tags: android

In an EditText functioning as a Search box, how do I find a **similar** word

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Rocki

Comment: i suggest you to search for autocompletetextView at http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/auto-complete-text-view-android.html

Answer (score 0):

AutocompletetextView is best one for do this: here is the link: http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/06/autocompletetextview-example.html

Answer (score 0):

you have two options

- AutoCompleteTextView

  check this [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)
- Edit text with `addTextChangedListener`

  Check this [List View with easy searching with EditText](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) documentation

> `AutoCompleteTextView` is an editable text view that shows completion
>   suggestions automatically while the user is typing.

Also read about [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

> A concrete `BaseAdapter` that is backed by an array of arbitrary
>   objects.

And try the following example from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```